# Unable to fetch command line arguments properly in C#

Tags: c#, command-line

In c#.Net I am not able to fetch the commandline argument properly.
It has problems in case i give the command like:

```
myProgram.exe "c:\inputfolder\" "d:\output.txt"
```

due to the backslash character(which i think acting as an escape character) in the args[] array i am getting only one argument instead of two
It works fine if i gave without backslash:

```
myProgram.exe "c:\inputfolder" "d:\output.txt"
```

or without double quotes:

```
myProgram.exe c:\inputfolder\ "d:\output.txt"
```

Answer (score 5):

I've never experienced such a problem but in case you like to parse the command line by your self use System.Environment.CommandLine to get it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a well known parsing problem and there isn't a whole lot you can do about it besides get the whole command line as a single string and parse it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The backslash is escaping the quote character in the shell. You have to use an extra backslash:

```
myProgram.exe "c:\inputfolder\\" "d:\output.txt"
```

You can use the following short sample program to test command line parsing:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Argument {0}: {1}", i, args[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thakns for reply ...
but this wount help me
User can give the input as 
myProgram.exe "c:\inputfolder\" "d:\output.txt"
I think anyhow i have to parse it.

Comment: I would suggest you print a reasonable error message in that case instead of handling the incorrect input. \" is the way the shell uses to pass a quote character to an application, you should not break that default behavior.

Comment: hi Divo, i think you have mistaken me.
I am using "visual studio 2008" for writing my c# appliction. 
I ve wrote program as suggested by you: 
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Argument {0}: {1}", i, args[i]));
        }
    }
.....
Input for the above program is - 
    myProgram.exe "c:\inputfolder" "d:\output.txt"

In the debug mode, when i put my cursor on the args[] array, it shows that the array contains only one item - 
  args[0] = "c:\inputfolder\" d:\output.txt"

Comment: Adding one more thing.... actually i need to separate further Validation of valid path... and it fails of course, because - 
(1). i am not getting the separate path 
(2). the value i am getting "c:\inputfolder\" d:\output.txt" has a double quote, hence fails against path validation
...I think this makes it more clear

Comment: the same problem occurs using the commandline arguments field in the project properties of visual studio 2005; +1 for the fix

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is trying to find official documentation on double-quotes in commandline args, the closest I could find was for c++ and it seems to directly apply: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx