# Problem parsing commandline arguments containing '&' character in C#.Net

Tags: c#, command-line

I am working in VisualStudio 2008 environment and developing a commandline application in C#.Net.
The application expects a path to be passed from the commandline argument.
I am passing these arguments to the to my application by setting the "Command line arguments" in the debug option of the project setting. The argument I provided is ->  "D:\Test\C&ID\Test data\a.dbf"

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

It works fine if I run the program using F5. Problem is when I use ctrl+F5. The `args[0]` contains

`D:\Test\C^&ID\Test data\a.dbf`

instead of

`D:\Test\C&ID\Test data\a.dbf`.

I am not able to grasp this that how come '&' is preceded by a '^' symbol. Further my path validation fails due to this. Can anyone please explain this to me. (Please note that the arguments provided are enclosed in double quotes and a part of it contains '&' character) And I think with this I have explained my problem :-)

Comment: fixed it for you, hope it is what you mean.

Comment: Hi Stefan,
This is a differnt problem what i asked earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792798/unable-to-fetch-command-line-arguments-properly-in-c). You said "fixed it for you" but where?

Comment: Have you tried running you application directly from the command line?  It could be a bug in the IDE.

Comment: @Chandra: you had a comment with a correction, now this comment has gone. You wrote C**^**ID and I fixed it and formatted it a bit. You can see the history when you click on the "edited ... ago" link.

Comment: Thats funny Stefan. About  C**^**ID, i actually typed C^ID and made '^' bold but it appeared as C**^**ID on this site. I am still struggling.... :(

Comment: Hi Jhon, I tried running with Command line, it works fine. But i am concern about the "ctrl+F5".

Answer (score 1):

Just checking -- you know that there is a different set of command line arguments per configuration, right?

So the command-line args in debug config (F5) might be different to the args in release config (ctrl+F5).

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Can u please elaborate this more. By the way, I have checked with both sets you mentioned - debug and release.